# Asp.Net Core Cache tag helpers still call the page handler?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, caching

the handler

```
    public void OnGet()
    {
        Menus = _context.Menus
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToList();
    }
```

on the page ~

```
<card>
    <card-header icon="fas fa-cubes" title="Atalhos">
</card-header>
    <card-body>
        <cache expires-after="@TimeSpan.FromHours(8)">
            <div class="list-group">
                @foreach (var item in Model.Menus)
                {
                    <a asp-page="@item.Url" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-light image-vibrate">
                        <i class="@item.Icon mr-2"></i>
                        @item.Name
                    </a>
                }
            </div>
        </cache>
    </card-body>
</card>
```

so i tried edit in the database and it won't update cause its being cached. But when I debug it still runs the page handler? Is this intended or am i missing something? I remember when i use ResponseCaching on MVC it never repeated the action

Comment: To me it seems logical. I think that the `OnGet()` is called every time the page is fetched from the server, and all the code in that method is executed. The server does not know that the Menu data will only be used on a part of e page that is already in the cache. I'm not too familiar with PageHandlers, but you need to somehow Lazy load the Menu object. It might be possible to break out the Menu rendering and loading into a partial view which output you can cache. More about partial views: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: A maybe quicker solution is to use the MemoryCache in the page handler and cache the data that is fetched from the database. This will of course not cache the output, but it might be a bit simpler to implement. MemoryCache: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @mortb i have used memoryCache before but i tried to avoid it because it can be complex to maintain